# Lock oracle apex application

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

It is possible to lock pages of an application in oracle apex(5.0). But I want to lock the entire application or entire pages in an application. How can I do this without visiting each page?

**Edit**: I want to restrict other developers from accessing this application, so that nobody else can make any changes without permission.

Comment: at this point you can only split by workspace, which is a sledgehammer for this requirement, I know.

Comment: ok.. Thank you @Scott. It would have been better if you write it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can lock the application in application properties: `Edit application properties` -> `Availability` -> `Build status`, set value `Run Application Only`. After that developers can't change the application. On attempt to edit, you will see the following:

[image]

To unlock application: go to `Application Builder` -> `Workspace Utilities`, in a side menu choose `Build and App Status`. A list of application appears. Choose an application and change its build status.

Comment: But this is a permenant change. I want to make it editable when required. is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you mean that you want to apply an "authorization scheme" to the entire application, which you can do by creating your own authorization scheme, then from the application's home page click the "Edit Application Properties" button, "Security" tab, then "Authorization".

Comment: But it works only while running application. I want to restrict other developers from accessing this application. Is that possible?